# Captured image do not get detected by the java program

Tags: java, swing, events, jpanel, actionlistener

In my java program I am making a GUI which is supposed to display the captured image in a `JPanel` on click of a `JButton`.

Below is the custom ImagePanel class which I have created to render the captured image.

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BufferedImage image;

    public ImagePanel() {
        try {
            File f = new File("capture.jpg");
            f.exists();  //this is returning false here, don't no why ?
            image = ImageIO.read(f); 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    }
}
```

and on click of JButton, in the ActionListener, I am doing the following action

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String s = e.getActionCommand();
        System.out.println(s);
        if (s.equals("Capture Image")) {
            //Here calling a script to capture the image.
            try {
                Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./capture.sh");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            ImagePanel  panel = new ImagePanel();
            containerPanel.add(panel);
            containerPanel.revalidate();
            containerPanel.repaint();
            .....
```

Still, my program is not able to detect the captured image and displaying it.However when I click the JButton next time it shows the previously captured image.

Even after lot of hustle, unable to detect the issue. Any help appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you get inside if ? That string comparing looks awful.

Why you don't use java 8 and lambda button.addActionListener((e) -> { // your code}) ?

Comment: @Lukino There's nothing wrong with his string comparison. In fact, I'd say it's much better to use `.equals()` compared to the lambda in general - what if a developer who doesn't use Java 8 and knows nothing about lambdas sees it? He'd be completely confused.

Comment: @Aify - then I recommend to get into that. It is like why using electricity for lighting room if there are still candles ? 

Behaviour based on string constant is not pretty when you need refactor. At least put it into Enum, so constant is in 1 place.

Comment: So where do you actually create the image??? Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. People are trying to answer with only half the information. Your ActionListener assumes the image has already been created.

Comment: @Lukino that's like saying "Why are you using a rowboat when you can use a motorboat?" Just because it's "newer" and "better"? What matters is that the previous method works - either boat can get you where you want to go. What if the person really likes rowboats? What if the developer really likes using `.equals()` for readability? Don't fix what's not broken unless it's necessary. There's no need to use lambdas at all.

Comment: A lambda expression is completely unnecessary for posting in a forum. You want as many people as possible to be able to read/execute your code.

Comment: @camickr updated the question about how i am capturing the image. also the image alwags get present after the capture. i have also mentioned in the question that previous image diplayed on the next click of the button.

Comment: @All - I did not say new is better and regarding executing code, not everything could be executed while sometimes it is only snippets and most parts are missing (because whole class is too big). However, I made a mistake to put this as an answer, but I still stands behind my comment. It was more an suggestion or hint. And in my opinion, it might be more readable that using log if-else or switch, you probably meant understandable.

Comment: @All now please donot spam here now, we got it by the first comment.

Comment: @camickr i am running this program on raspberry pi, and the image is captured by the camera attached to it.

Comment: @Bruce_Wayne, `the image is captured by the camera attached to it.` - see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

You state:

```
File f = new File(capture.jpg); // ****this compiles without quotes?????
f.exists();  //this is returning false
image = ImageIO.read(f);
```

It's likely false because your path is wrong. Remember that when using Files, the path is relative to the user.dir path. To check to see what the user directory is, simply print out:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Better probably to use resources and not files,...

```
InputStream iStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("capture.jpg");
image = ImageIO.read(iStream);
```

When using resources, the path will be relative to the classpath -- the location of the class files, not the user directory.

Comment: And you both missing quotes. But that sound about right.

Comment: @Lukino: but mine comments that it shouldn't compile!

Comment: Oh, sorry, you just copied it, but you using quotes in getResourceAsStream. Retracting half of my comment ;-)

Comment: @Lukino my capture.jpg is present in the same directory as the program. do i still need to give the complete path ??

Comment: @Bruce_Wayne: Again, please use the image as a resource as I have shown you.

Comment: @Bruce_Wayne - this answer is everything you need. I was just pointing out missing quotes (code will not compile)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels but using your code it is giving null pointer exception. iStream remains null. it is not picking image.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels fine delete you answer  i will delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that continually updates a JLabel with an image:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ImageReload extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    JLabel timeLabel;
    JLabel imageLabel;
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("timeLabel.jpg");

    public ImageReload()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        timeLabel = new JLabel( new Date().toString() );
        imageLabel = new JLabel( timeLabel.getText() );

        add(timeLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        timeLabel.setText( new Date().toString() );

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    String imageName = "timeLabel.jpg";
                    BufferedImage image = ScreenImage.createImage(timeLabel);
                    ScreenImage.writeImage(image, imageName);

                    InputStream iStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageName);
                    imageLabel.setIcon( new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( iStream ) ) );

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println( e );
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new ImageReload() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This example also requires the usage of the [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class.

Edit:

> it shows the previously captured image.

So I would guess the problem is that your code is executing before the image has been written. I know nothing about your camera app.

Maybe you can use the `Process.waitFor()` method to wait for the process to finish.

Or maybe you should be using a `SwingWorker.

Comment: It's kind of a shifting requirements type problem, one that's always very difficult to answer. 1+ for your attempt.

Comment: @camickr thanks for your effort, mind removing your answer i am thinking of deleting the question.